# How Browsers deal with UTF8MB4

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, utf-8

I'm working on my own version of tweetdeck with the twitter API.

EVERYTHING IS WORKING :), If pull the results directly from twitter I get to see those nice iphone UTF8MB4 smileys in OSX Safari browser. I even got mySQL server to support UTF8MB4.

Alas, it ONLY works in OSX Safari, Chrome in OSX doesn't work, and nothing in windows does.

instead i Get white boxs. here are a few, I wonder how they look to you!

Anyway, my question is, would it be possible to write a javascript based plugin for chrome that detects UTF8MB4 characters and replaces them with image icons? Even though a character  isn't found and the question box is shown, is chromes engine recognizing the character discretely?

I really don't know how Chrome or Windows handles UTF8MB4. Linux seems to like it, but I'm always accessing it through a OSX SSH session so maybe it's just that.

Thanks for he help.

Comment: AFAIK "UTF8MB4" is the way MySQL refers to the actual UTF-8 encoding (because MySQL's "UTF8" encoding is limited to 3 bytes characters).

Comment: The smileys look perfectly fine on my Windows 7 machine with Firefox.

Comment: And if by "smileys" you mean those astral plane characters, their support greatly vary in different OS/browsers.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it is just chrome and IE then? Could you seen me a screen shot, maybe the firefox engine does what I am thinking (I don't know of a windows font with the 4-bit smileys, but would be curious?)

Comment: Fabricio. UTF8MB4 with 4-byte support was added in 5.5.3

Comment: Yes I know. I meant that MySQL's UTF8MB4 == (any other program's) UTF8.

Comment: Your first 'smiley' seems to be from UTF8's fifth plane, those characters outside of the plane 0 don't render very consistently across different OS and browsers as far as I'm aware.

Comment: thats the whole point, I don't care what they render as, I'm wondering if javascript would recognize each one for a regexp replace command?

Comment: I believe so -- rendering should not affect the elements' text content. Never tested though. Oh sorry, missed that paragraph about the JS question.

Comment: NP I guess it's worth pursuing then! thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

someone beat me to the punch! I found a chrome extension that does exactually what I was thinking, it converts the UTF8MB4 characters with small .gif images that represent the iOS display of said characters. So this confirms that chrome does indeed recognize UTF8MB4 characters, it just doesn't have native display support for them.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromoji-emoji-for-google/cahedbegdkagmcjfolhdlechbkeaieki/related?hl=en-GB

I supposed anyone could write their own version of this extension, but no reason to reinvent the wheel